# Calling function onload based on the ID of body

Tags: jquery, onload, jquery-events

I would like to initialize a few elements on load of the page. On different pages, different elements need to be initialized, however, I would like keep all if it in a single file. So I would like to attach a different function to the `body.onload`, based on the ID of the page.

Can anyone please tell me if that is possible? If it is, please explain how it can be done.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Depending on the number of pages, you may be creating a maintenance nightmare.  The solution will depend in part on the tools you're using to build the site.

Comment: make the pageid available to javascript and you can do whatever you want with it. Where do you decide the pageid/name ? what is the server side language you use? php? asp? or anyother ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var bodyId = $('body').attr('id');

    if (bodyId == 'id1')
        myFunction1();
    elseif (bodyId == 'id2')
        myFunction2();

});
```

You should rather use CSS classes than IDs for this type of thing.

Comment: i think he din't mean the body id. He meant the pageid/name that he sets at the server side.

Comment: Stefan, Thanks for the solution. I thought of this, but I wanted to avoid having large condition block. It could really slow down considering that I have a large range of page IDs.

Answer (score 1):

One possible pattern would be something like this:

```
var Controller = {
    homePage: function() { alert('home'); },
    contactPage = function() { alert('contact'); }
};
```

Then, on your individual pages:

```
$(function() {
    var id = $(body).attr('id');
    Controller[id]();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a file in which you could put object literal with keys referring to each identifiers that you have in body tag.  And calls them depending of current body id.

For example

```
    var callbacks= { 
              "id_of_body1": function(){ 
                  // will trigger when body tag will id_of_body1
              },
              "id_of_body2": function(){ 
                  // will trigger when body tag will id_of_body2
              } 
    }
  // or $(document).ready - if you would call function after document is loaded
 // or $(fn) what is shortcut   for $(document).ready(fn)
  $('body').bind('load', function(){  
       callbacks[$(this).attr('id')].apply(this,arguments)
  } )
```

Comment: I think he means the ID of the page (that he sets on the server side) and not the id of body element of the page.

Comment: The mechanism works, and how will you take the id doesn't matter.
I mean, I leave it to the author

Comment: I actually meant the ID attribute of the page Boopati.

Comment: Thanks Abuduba, I really like this solution. I just hope it works on most browsers. IE7 upwards. I assume it will work on webkit and mozilla browsers.

Comment: This will work wherever jQuery is supported ( IE6+ and rather, all of the modern browsers).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, first make the pageid available to JavaScript

```
<?php echo "<script>var pageid={$mypageid};</script>"; ?>
```

For other server-side languages, use something similar. This should be echoed in the head part. So that body onload will have this variable alive.

Then you can use this to select the set of statements that needs to be executed based on pageid either using a `switch_case` inside onload event handler or using a `js object` as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('body#your-id').each(function() {
  listOfFunctions();
});
```